# What is the XSL version supported by xalan 1.8 library

Tags: xslt, xalan

What is the **XSL** version supported by **Xalan** 1.8 library ?

Answer (score 2):

The XSLT version that is supported by all versions of Xalan is XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the XSL version supported by Xalan 1.8 library ?

1.0

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it changes in the future: generally, you can ask any XSLT processor to report on the version it supports with:

`<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />`